# Querying Bigtable by column values

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Is there any programmatic way to query Bigtable without using rowkey and by querying on column values directly?

I assume we can do that as external tables on BigQuery, and through the api by scanning entire Bigtable and applying filter. But is there any better way?

Comment: Using [HBase for your BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-bigtable) you can have bloom filters which gives you the ability to check whether or not a SSTable contains any specific data in row/column pair. You can take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-bigtable) and also to these [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281015/8963486).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bigtable is a row-based datastore where BigQuery is a column-based datastore, so there isn't a way to perform the queries you're trying to do without a full table scan or using a [federated query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable). If this you see yourself planning to run a lot of queries like this regularly, I'd recommend duplicating your data between Bigtable and BigQuery which is a fairly common solution. You can either add a fork to your current ingestion flow or write a Dataflow job that moves your data from one to the other at a regularly scheduled interval.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to create an other table with moving the values in the columns to the key. You will duplicate your data in this way, but you can search it fast and make range scans.